# Unable to install/update any package/conda/navigator?

Tags: python, anaconda, upgrade, conda

I am having an issue with upgrading and installing package on Anaconda.

It appears that trying to `install` or `upgrade` packages fails. But so does updating `conda` and `anaconda-navigator`.

I most online help I found the first recommended step was to update `conda`, but I can't even do that.

I have tried running the command through the Anaconda Prompt ran as Admin without success.

The error is a `RecursionError` tracing back to line 365 in the `_build_components` file:

```
return frozendict(_make(key, value) for key, value in iteritems(kwargs))
```

My conda version is 4.4.10, the conda-build version is 3.4.1, the python version is 3.6.4.final.0

I had a look at the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362389/unable-to-upgrade-conda-and-install-packages-using-conda) but it is not the same problem.

An answer or any direction as to where I might find an answer would be great !

Here is the entire log output that I reformatted:

```
'command': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//Scripts//conda install --yes --json --force-pscheck --prefix C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3 anaconda-navigator==1.9.6',
'conda_info': {
    'active_prefix': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
    'active_prefix_name': 'base',
    'channels': [
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64',
      'https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch'
    ],
    'conda_build_version': '3.4.1',
    'conda_env_version': '4.4.10',
    'conda_location': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda',
    'conda_prefix': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
    'conda_private': false,
    'conda_shlvl': -1,
    'conda_version': '4.4.10',
    'config_files': [
      'C://Users//Sorade//.condarc'
    ],
    'default_prefix': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
    'env_vars': {
      'CIO_TEST': '<not set>',
      'CONDA_PREFIX': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
      'CONDA_ROOT': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
      'GTK_BASEPATH': 'C://Program Files (x86)//GtkSharp//2.12//',
      'HOMEPATH': '//Users//Sorade',
      'PATH': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3;C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//Library//mingw-w64//bin;C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//Library//usr//bin;C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//Library//bin;C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//Scripts;C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//Library//bin;C://WINDOWS//system32;C://WINDOWS;C://WINDOWS//System32//Wbem;C://WINDOWS//System32//WindowsPowerShell//v1.0//;C://Program Files (x86)//ATI Technologies//ATI.ACE//Core-Static;C://Program Files (x86)//GtkSharp//2.12//bin;C://Android;C://Windows//System32;C://WINDOWS//System32//OpenSSH//;C://Users//Sorade//AppData//Local//Microsoft//WindowsApps',
      'PSMODULEPATH': 'C://WINDOWS//system32//WindowsPowerShell//v1.0//Modules//',
      'REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE': '<not set>',
      'SSL_CERT_FILE': '<not set>'
    },
    'envs': [],
    'envs_dirs': [
      'D://Documents//Loisirs//Programming//Anaconda3_envs',
      'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//envs',
      'C://Users//Sorade//AppData//Local//conda//conda//envs',
      'C://Users//Sorade//.conda//envs'
    ],
    'is_windows_admin': true,
    'netrc_file': null,
    'offline': false,
    'pkgs_dirs': [
      'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//pkgs',
      'C://Users//Sorade//AppData//Local//conda//conda//pkgs'
    ],
    'platform': 'win-64',
    'python_version': '3.6.4.final.0',
    'rc_path': 'C://Users//Sorade//.condarc',
    'requests_version': '2.18.4',
    'root_prefix': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
    'root_writable': true,
    'site_dirs': [],
    'sys.executable': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//python.exe',
    'sys.prefix': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3',
    'sys.version': '3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]',
    'sys_rc_path': 'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//.condarc',
    'user_agent': 'conda/4.4.10 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134',
    'user_rc_path': 'C://Users//Sorade//.condarc'
  },
  'error': 'RecursionError(\'maximum recursion depth exceeded\',)',
  'exception_name': 'RecursionError',
  'exception_type': '<class \'RecursionError\'>',
  'traceback': 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//exceptions.py/', line 789, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//cli//main.py/', line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//cli//conda_argparse.py/', line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//cli//main_install.py/', line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, \'install\')
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//cli//install.py/', line 236, in install
    force_reinstall=context.force,
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//core//solve.py/', line 504, in solve_for_transaction
    force_remove, force_reinstall)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//core//solve.py/', line 437, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//core//solve.py/', line 218, in solve_final_state
    _, inconsistent_dists = r.bad_installed(solution, ())
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//resolve.py/', line 731, in bad_installed
    C = r2.gen_clauses()
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//resolve.py/', line 509, in gen_clauses
    C.Require(C.Or, nkey, self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms))
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//resolve.py/', line 481, in push_MatchSpec
    m = C.from_name(self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms2))
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//resolve.py/', line 481, in push_MatchSpec
    m = C.from_name(self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms2))
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//resolve.py/', line 481, in push_MatchSpec
    m = C.from_name(self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms2))
  [Previous line repeated 966 more times]
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//resolve.py/', line 480, in push_MatchSpec
    ms2 = MatchSpec(track_features=tf) if tf else MatchSpec(nm)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//models//match_spec.py/', line 76, in __call__
    return super(MatchSpecType, cls).__call__(**kwargs)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//models//match_spec.py/', line 178, in __init__
    self._match_components = self._build_components(**kwargs)
  File /'C://Users//Sorade//Anaconda3//lib//site-packages//conda//models//match_spec.py/', line 365, in _build_components
    return frozendict(_make(key, value) for key, value in iteritems(kwargs))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
'
}
Upload successful.
. Error - Extra data: line 73 column 1 (char 6530)"
```

Comment: Maybe corrupted ? 
You should try a clean : https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-clean.html

Comment: What are the likely consequence of `conda clean -all` ? I did a dry run and it would remove over 900 MB, that seems like a lot. Would my environments be safe ?

Comment: Yes, `conda clean` only removes files that are no longer necessary. However, I doubt that's the problem here. Can you please post the entire output?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. How do I get the log file ? At the moment it only appears in the console

Comment: @darthbith I have just updated the question with full log report

Comment: Can you try `conda update --force --no-deps conda`? Hopefully that will force it to update conda without checking the dependencies that is causing the recursion error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and I still get the same error. I really don't know where it could be coming from. I use the Anaconda prompt run as admin, should I be using Windows cmd as admin instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You may no longer be having this issue, but for others (like me) who encounter the exact same problem. I was using conda version 4.4.10 and I could not update any packages. I tried all suggestions on this page (and many others), but nothing worked. I eventually downloaded conda version 4.5.0 from https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/, which (I think) should list conda packages that tally with the list given by:

```
conda search conda
```

Place the bz2 file in your C:/User/Name/ directory, then run:

```
conda update conda-4.5.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 --offline
```

Following this, the conda update/install should work, allowing all other packages to be updated.